# Limiting the number of results of should clauses in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm writing a query to get results matching one of multiple phrases, like

```
{
  'size': 10,
  'from': 0,

  'query': {
    'bool': {
      'should': [
        {'text': {'title': { 'query': 'some words' }}},
        {'text': {'title': { 'query': 'other words' }}},
        {'text': {'title': { 'query': 'some other words' }}},
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

It works as expected, but I have a problem : the 10 scored results are all matching the same phrase.

The solution I thought of was to limit the number of results from each `should` clause to 5 elements for example.

The problem is that I don't see how to implement this using Elastic Search queries, and I don't know if it possible, or if it exists another way to do what I want.

Any ideas ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 12, accepted):

ElasticSearch is looking for the "most relevant" docs matching your query, while you are trying to achieve a union of 3 queries.

The simplest (and fastest) way to do this would be to run three queries, using [multi search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html):

```
curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/my_index/_msearch?pretty=1'  -d '
{}
{"query" : {"text" : {"title" : "some words"}}, "size" : 5}
{}
{"query" : {"text" : {"title" : "some other words"}}, "size" : 5}
{}
{"query" : {"text" : {"title" : "other words"}}, "size" : 5}
'
```

An alternative, depending on your requirements may be to use the [limit filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/limit-filter.html), but note that it limits the number of results PER SHARD, not per index.  By default, an index has 5 primary shards, so if you specify a limit of 5, you may well get 25 results back.

So perhaps something like this:

```
curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/_all/_search?pretty=1'  -d '
{
   "query" : {
      "bool" : {
         "should" : [
            {
               "filtered" : {
                  "filter" : {
                     "limit" : {
                        "value" : 1
                     }
                  },
                  "query" : {
                     "text" : {
                        "title" : "some words"
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "filtered" : {
                  "filter" : {
                     "limit" : {
                        "value" : 1
                     }
                  },
                  "query" : {
                     "text" : {
                        "title" : "other words"
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "filtered" : {
                  "filter" : {
                     "limit" : {
                        "value" : 1
                     }
                  },
                  "query" : {
                     "text" : {
                        "title" : "some other words"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
'
```

This would give you the top scoring doc for each phrase on each shard (with 5 shards, a maximum of 15 docs, which (because you haven't specified `size=15`) would be reduced to the top 10 docs).

Your mileage may vary, depending on how your docs are distributed across your shards.

Comment: Thanks for the multi-search advice !